# Is there way to copy CSV like text string to 2D Array?

Tags: java, arrays

How do I split and copy text String to 2D Array in Java? 
String values are

```
String input=`[1,Mumbai][2,Delhi][3,Chennai]`
```

I like to split and copy to 2D String array.

My original data was in 2D String on Java Servlet. I copied that Array into StringBuilder and returned to Java class. From here in order to use this data I want to bring it back to 2D Array.

```
StringBuilder mbuscat = new StringBuilder();
String[][] abuscat = new String[11][2];
String lineSeparator = System.lineSeparator();
int b=0;
while(rset.next()) {         
                abuscat[b][0] = rset.getString(1);
                abuscat[b][1] = rset.getString(2);
                b ++;
            }
for (String[] row : abuscat) {
    mbuscat.append(Arrays.toString(row))
      .append(lineSeparator);
}
```

I expect output like

```
 arry[0][0]="1"
 arry[0][1]="mumbai"
 arry[1][0]="2"
 arry[1][1]="delhi"
 arry[2][0]="3"
 arry[2][1]="chennai"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `String#split` might work here:

```
String input = "[1,Mumbai][2,Delhi][3,Chennai]";
String[][] abuscat;
String[] parts = input.split("(?<=\\])(?=\\[)");
abuscat = new String[parts.length][2];

for (int r=0; r < parts.length; ++r) {
    abuscat[r][0] = parts[r].replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "").split(",")[0];
    abuscat[r][1] = parts[r].replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "").split(",")[1];
}

System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(abuscat));
```

Output:

```
[[1, Mumbai], [2, Delhi], [3, Chennai]]
```

Comment: the split returns an array so you can assign this array to abuscat[r]:`abuscat[r]=parts[r].replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "").split(",");`